# Regular Expression to test a package like com.abcd.efghij in java script

Tags: javascript

I want to test if user has entered a package or not, else I need to throw an error.
I am using the below expression:

```
new RegExp("([a-zA-Z]+)(\.[a-zA-Z]+)(\.[a-zA-Z]+)$");
```

Its not working. Since I am new to RegExp, can someone tell me where it went wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the backslashes, because they have special meaning in string literals:

```
var re = new RegExp("([a-zA-Z]+)(\\.[a-zA-Z]+)(\\.[a-zA-Z]+)$");
```

Or you could use a RegExp literal:

```
var re = /([a-zA-Z]+)(\.[a-zA-Z]+)(\.[a-zA-Z]+)$/;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why it does not work.

`^([a-z]+)\.([a-z]+)\.([a-z]+)$`

http://regex101.com/r/mR9kB6